# Using computed property in Ember to get model data and display extra text

Tags: ember.js

In my Ember template, I want to be able to loop over each item coming from the model (an array) and if the value is 'blue', display some text next to the value.

My template looks like this:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    <h2>Loop over colors</h2>
    <ul>
        {{#each color in model}}
            <li>{{color}} {{#if isBlue}} - Its Blue!{{/if}}  </li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</script>
```

And my app.js file looks like this:

```
App = Ember.Application.create({});

App.Router.map( function() {

    this.resource( 'about');

});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return ['red', 'yellow', 'blue'];
  }
});

App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    isBlue: function() {
        return this.get('content') == 'blue';
    }.property()
});
```

I'm using *this.get('content')* because I thought that was supposed to be a reference to the actual model data.

I've tried numerous variations of the code but I'm now blocked. Hope someone can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are defining the `isBlue` property on the IndexController, which is an ArrayController, and not on each item in the content. You can instruct the `{{each}}` helper to use an [`itemController`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#method_each) for each item in the loop. By doing that you are able to define additional computed properties, that are not present in the original objects, and make them available within the `each` loop:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    <h2>Loop over colors</h2>
    <ul>
        {{#each color in model itemController="color"}}
            <li>{{color}} {{#if isBlue}} - Its Blue!{{/if}}</li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</script>

App.ColorController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  isBlue: function() {
    return this.get('content') === 'blue';
  }.property('content')
});
```

You can also check out [JSBIN](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/qoheqeda/4/edit).

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayController` means that the `content` property is an array, not just an object. Also, you don't want to access `content` directly. Controllers proxy their models, so use the controller as if it was an array. So your `isBlue` function is wrong in a few ways. It's *probably* possible to do what you want using the `isBlue` property, but I would use something like this:

```
colorItems: Em.computed.map('@this', function(color) {
    return {
        color: color,
        isBlue: color === 'blue'
    };
})
```

Then, in your template:

```
{{#each colorItems}}
    <li>
        {{color}} 
        {{#if isBlue}}
             - It's Blue!
        {{/if}}
    </li>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: That would go in your controller.